# Spring Data MongoDB Testing

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I wrote a small study-project to play a little bit with mongodb. I was using Spring Data to get Mongo Repository. It was quite easy to create RestController and using MongoRepository through Service (another class) retrieve info from mongodb and render it to the browser.

```
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, Integer> {
    List<Person> findByName(String name);
    @Query("{'name':{$regex:?0}}")
    List<Person> findByNameLike(String nameLike);
    //the rest of methods
}
```

Now I decided to test my business logic and created the following class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class})
public class TestMongo {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestMongo.class);

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Technology technology1 = new Technology("Java-7");
        Technology technology2 = new Technology("Java-8");
        Technology technology3 = new Technology("Hibernate");
        Technology technology4 = new Technology("MyBatis");
        Technology technology5 = new Technology("Spring Data");

        Project project1 = new Project(1, "POINT", Arrays.asList(technology1, technology3));
        Project project2 = new Project(2, "Forecast", Arrays.asList(technology1, technology4));
        Project project3 = new Project(3, "CPM", Arrays.asList(technology2, technology5));

        Person person1 = new Person(1, "Alex", 27, Arrays.asList(project1, project3));
        Person person2 = new Person(2, "Ivan", 26, Arrays.asList(project2, project3));
        Person person3 = new Person(3, "Andrii", 31, Arrays.asList(project1));

        personRepository.save(Arrays.asList(person1, person2, person3));
    }

    @Test
    public void count() {
        List<Person> all = personRepository.findAll();
        LOG.info("There are " + all.size() + " person(s) in database");
        assertThat(all.size(), equalTo(3));
    }

    @Test
    public void findByName() {
        List<Person> personList = personRepository.findByName("Ivan");
        LOG.info("*******Find by name********");
        LOG.info("personList {}", personList);
        LOG.info("***************************");
        assertThat(personList, hasSize(1));
    }

    //another test methods

    @After
    public void shutDown() {
        personRepository.deleteAll();
    }
}
```

where `AppConfig.class` looks as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
@ComponentScan
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        return new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoClient(),"my-mongo");
    }
}
```

And now my problem: I don't actually want to run some tests on the same database where I store my data. Moreover, I have a crucial method `personRepository.deleteAll()` after which all the data will just vanish.
I found embedded mongodb as a solution but once I add it to my `pom.xml` I don't see my installed database anymore.
So, the question is whether it's possible to have both installed and embedded mongodb on the same machine and if not how to test my MongoRepository without modifying prod data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I found what I was missing:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
    <version>1.50.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Simply adding scope test is launching my embedded mongodb for tests only, while I'm still using installed mongodb for prod.